# Could electric grids of the past have handled significant quantities of variable energy sources like wind and solar?

Tags: energy

Would the technology for electricity grid load balance in the 1930’s allowed for the significant use of decentralized variable energy sources like wind or solar.  Setting aside the plausibility of having wind and solar, could grid managers have reasonably handled a grid of 30-40% variable sources(wind turbines, concentrating solar) combined with storage (pumped hydro, flywheels, compressed air, etc) and the rest comprised of baseload sources (hydro, biomass and biogas, geothermal)?

Comment: What do you mean by "the technology for electricity grid load balance in the 1930s"? The first large-scale electrical power grids only emerged in the late 1930s, and near-real-time power generation / load management dispatching operators became a thing only in the 1950s. In short, what you are asking about did not exist.

Comment: I suppose this gets at my question.  It has been difficult for me to find information on how electric grids worked in the past.  If near-real-time power generation only emerged in the 1950s as you say, how was electricity demand and supply managed before that to avoid load imbalances leading to black outs.  Would intermediate energy sources added a unmanageable level of complexity?  Would they have been able to efficiently utilize energy storage methods to mitigate some of the intermediacy issues?

Comment: Before the mid-1930s there were no [wide area synchronous grids](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wide_area_synchronous_grid) at all, so all power generation management was a local thing, and nobody was all that fussy about having *exactly* 50 or 60 Hz. National grids began emerging in the late 1930s, but the interconnections between power plants were still feeble, so that power generation balancing remained pretty much local. Only in the 1950s do we see true national power grids and the beginnings of interconnects between national grids. For that point on we do have national power dispatchers.

Comment: Nowadays, [ENTSO-E](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/European_Network_of_Transmission_System_Operators_for_Electricity) (the top-level power transmission operator for Europe) becomes agitated if the AC frequency [drops to 49.996 Hz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wide_area_synchronous_grid#Timekeeping), but in the 1930s nobody would have blinked at 49.5 Hz or 50.5 hz. (Power consumption is very roughly proportional to AC frequency, so allowing for wider tolerances allows more time to react.) (And steam-driven turbines and generators have a ton of mechanical inertia, so small bumps are smoothed.)

Comment: In the 30s, local, renewable energy sources would have been a solution to *another* problem.. it was very expensive to connect rural communities to the electricity net. Using solar and wind, with smaller, local equipment, these communities would have been able to take care of electricity production themselves. Their electricity would not have reached a grid. The "grid" is an invention of 1926, quite recent https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrical_grid

Answer (score 6):

### Power grids have always handled variances of over 40%

Even when you run a coal plant, you do not run it at 100% all the time.  You shut down some of the turbines at night when you need less power and turn them back on mid-day when you need more. Many modern appliances like air conditioners, water heaters, and refrigerators are always on, but back in the 30s, these mostly did not exist.  Instead, nearly all household power was used for lighting meaning that your time-of-day power variance would have been much higher than it is now.  So, they had to engineer their power grid around even larger fluctuations in load strengths than we see today.

How you would handle this in your setting is by using the variable power sources as they are available and increasing the variance on your more controllable power sources.  So instead of having 5-10 turbines running on your hydroelectric powerplant at a time, you might have 1-10 turbines running, depending on what you are also currently getting out of your wind/solar/etc.

As for gauging the changes in the power grid, both the Vibrating Reed Meter and various forms of Moving Needle Systems were already invented by the late 1800s; so, by the 1930s, power grids were already very good at detecting changes in power throughput to the electric grid in real time.

Comment: Thanks for the comment.  What I'm interested in finding out, is how grid managers could have monitored input from different sources.  Naturally, they did not have the complex grid management software used today.  How would they know to turn on/off turbines in your example, or when to capture/release stored energy?

Comment: @greenbeardj: Ah, that is what you want to know? Basically, they monitor the AC frequency. If the load is higher than what the generators can carry, then the frequency drops. If the generators produce more power than needed, the frequency increases. They would have used something like a [vibrating reed frequency meter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frequency_meter), which can be arranged to give [immediate visual feedback](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xJGsVrs9El8). (Note that the meter in the linked video is scaled from 48 to 52 Hz, showing how wide were the tolerances for grid AC freq.)

Comment: @greenbeardj that is a very different question. Seeing as a relatively modern electricity grid like the Netherlands clearly is outdated for the influx of all the new solar, wind and other alternative sources I would say no. Note that this problem seems to mainly comes from individual sources like solar pannels on individual houses, as the electricity grid isn't created to redustribute this. Though large solar pannel arrays or wind farms by big companies are certainly also affected/part of the problem for the current net. ...

Comment: (Cont.) When electricity grids were proposed a distributed system was also in mind. If this was done from the beginning it might fare much better.

Answer (score 2):

My Father was a hydro-electric power station operator in the 70's. Because hydro stations can respond quickly to load changes unlike thermal stations it was used to balance load in the local grid. The State grid was fully interconnected (NSW - Australia). Each local area was under the management of a County Council. His area was about 600 x 400 km. Frequency and the balance between capacitive (fluorescent lights) and inductive loads (stoves & motors) were monitored on analog gagues by an operator in real time who would manually  adjust station output to stabilize both frequency and phase lag.
Peaks typically occurred in the evening when folk came home, switched on lighting and started cooking dinner.
As fluorescent lighting and electric stoves were dominant it went like this.
In summer inductive load would peak first as folk started cooking. This would then drop & capacitive load would creep up as lights were switched on. In winter it was the reverse.
There would also be another, mostly inductive, peak in the morning as industry came on.